# How to repair a compass when I accidentally switched it's poles?

Tags: electromagnetism

I like to play with magnets, and at some time I wanted to know the pole orientation of one.
The compass now has inverse poles.
And I do not know how that happened!

I have no memory how that happened, because I m noticed it at some time after taking it from it's storage place. So I do not have the slightest idea what I did last before.

The way I know to reverse poles of a permanent magnet is to bring it 
antiparallel to a much stronger magnet, which has the desired poling.
Butt that does not work for an encapsulated compass, because that reverses its spacial orientation, before the stronger magnet is near enough ro reverse poles. The compass is fluid damped and can not be closed after opening it.

Comment: Since it is damped,  maybe you could bring one pole of the magnet close and then flip it very quickly before the compass has time to reverse.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confused about the compass markings?  The pole of a compass that is attracted to the Earth's *North* Magnetic Pole is a   ______   Pole?

Comment: @DJohnM I have two compasses pointing in opposite directions - so **at least one is wrong**. But I was confused when thinking about that.